# weird permission issue while deleting android bookmarks

Tags: android, permissions, bookmarks

I'm facing some permission issue while deleting android bookmarks:

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.browser.provider.BrowserProvider2 uri content://browser/bookmarks from pid=8045, uid=10028 requires com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS`

The problem is, I've already set that permission in manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.broswer.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this is a copy paste of your permission, you wrote broswer and not browser

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I am not getting what do you mean by `you wrote broswer and not browser`. can you plz explain it.

Comment: He made a typo in the permission and wrote broswer instead of browser

Comment: No problem +1 if i could help ;)

Comment: Also check that you're typed uses-permission and not uses-permissions (Singular).